# Subset according to patterns in file names

Tags: r, regex

I have the following file names in a folder:

> 1_myfile.txt, 2_myfile.txt, 3_myfile.txt, and 4_best_myfile.txt, 5_best_myfile.txt, 6_best_myfile.txt.

I would like to use regex in pattern = "" when listing files with `list.files()` in order to subset files containing "_myfile.txt" from files containing "_best_myfile.txt". I tried using:

```
 files = list.files(path = ".", "*[^best_myfile.txt]$")
```

Unfortunately it does not work because it subsets only files that do not end with `.txt`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use `"\\d+_best_myfile.txt"` without the `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can modify the `pattern` to `"\\d+_best_myfile\\.txt"`

```
files <- list.files("\\d+_best_myfile\\.txt")
```

It implies one or more numbers (`\\d+`) followed by a `_` and the string `best_myfile.txt`.  Also, note that some characters needs to be escaped i.e. `.` is a metacharacter and it implies any character.  So, to get the literal dot character, we need to escape (`\\`) it

Comment: This work very well and thank you so much for that. Unfortunately I'm not able to subset files containing only myfile.

Comment: @Bfu38  I am not sure about your second comment.  Perhaps `^\\d+_myfile\\.txt$"` is what you wanted

Comment: Sorry If I was not so clear but when I tried to subset, my code was not able to distinguish between "_myfile.txt" and "_best_myfile.txt" that is the major aim of my attempts.

Comment: @Bfu38  You can use `grepl("best", list.files())` to get a logical index if that is what you want

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun. That was my aim. It works fine.